# Creating entities from a postgresql 9.0.1 database with Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: postgresql, jpa, netbeans-6.9

Basically it doesn't work ... I can install the jdbc driver for pg 90 in netbeans and browse the database, issue sql commands etc. But creating entity beans from the tables via the same connection does not work, Netbeans can't find any tables in the database. Do I have to downgrade to pg 84, or are there some tricks to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It happends when using custom domains: Netbeans can see the table but does not generate the entity bean.

I tried to define a table with no custom domains (VARCHAR or INTEGER only) and the entity has been created correctly

A Netbeans bug, I think.